# How do I increase the size of this map?

Tags: google-maps

```
<!--
  copyright (c) 2009 Google inc.

  You are free to copy and use this sample.
  License can be found here: 

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/faq/#license
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; 

charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geomap']});

    function drawVisualization() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addRows(6);
      data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Popularity');

      data.setValue(1, 0, 'United 10:19 AM 8/16/2010States');
      data.setValue(1, 1, 300);
     var options = { region: 'us_metro' };

      var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(
          document.getElementById('visualization'));
      geomap.draw(data, options);
    }


    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="visualization" style="width: 800px; height: 

400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
​
```

Comment: Gee. Thanks for that. Do you have a question about this then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding GeoMap,[this](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap.html#Configuration_Options) can help

```
  options['width']='800';
  options['height']= '600';
  geomap.draw(data,options);
```

Answer (score 2):

To increase the size of the map visualization, you have to **change the pixel values in the `style` attribute of `<div id="visualization" ...`**.

For example:

```
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="visualization" style="width: 1600px; height: 800px;"></div>
</body>
```

---

Also, I noticed that you're using the Google Visualization API. Unless you're going to be showing some charts or creating an intensity or geo map, **I recommend you use the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html)** - you can manipulate many more things about the map.

Comment: nope i dont believe that is right. btw do you have family in CT?

Comment: @I__ have you tried it? I don't think there is another way. Also, what does CT stand for? :)

Comment: shalom maxim, have you worked with google chart geo map/map before?

Comment: @I__ I've worked with the Google Maps API to build multiple applications, including websites using the Maps JavaScript API and geocoding functions using the Maps Geocoding API.

However, I haven't used the Google Visualization API to accomplish functions that the Maps API supports.

Comment: Not sure why OP voted this as correct. It doesn't work. Try the answer below by @neer for a working solution.